# How to Activate Tab IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to set selected tab in objective c,
 i am adding tab programmatically,
 Here  is my code for that:

```
#import "TabControllerViewController.h"
#import "DetailsView.h"

@interface TabControllerViewController (){
  NSMutableArray *kirtanDetail;
  CGPoint startPosition;
}

@end

@implementation TabControllerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  dbm=[[DBManager alloc]init];
  [dbm openDB];
  kirtanDetail=[dbm getAllPad:[NSString              stringWithFormat:@"%@",_kirtanID]];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  [self addTabView:[kirtanDetail count]];
  [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"activeTab" object:@"2"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


 -(void)addTabView:(NSInteger *) tab {
   UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"     bundle:nil];
   NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for(int i=0;i<tab;i++){
     UIViewController *view1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"DV"];
     [view1 viewDidLoad];
     [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
     //can't set this until after its added to the tab bar
     view1.tabBarItem =[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"PAD %d",i+1] image:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"view1"]tag:i];

     UITextView *textView=[[view1.view subviews]objectAtIndex:0 ];
     NSArray *data=[kirtanDetail objectAtIndex:i];
     if([[data objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@",_kirtanID]]){
        NSLog(@"Active TAB=%d",i);

   }
   textView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dbm     getKirtanDetails:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data     objectAtIndex:0]]]];

}
[self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

}
-(void)setActiveTab:(NSNotification *)notification{
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:[notification object]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Add this after viewDidLoad, in viewWillAppear

EDIT:
Is this controller TabControllerViewController subclass of UITabBarController or UIVIewController? If it's subclass of UITabBarController then replace `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` with `[self setSelectedindex:1]`

Comment: When did you try it? In which method (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear)?

Comment: i had try in both method

Comment: Is this controller `TabControllerViewController` subclass  of UITabBarController or UIVIewController? If it's subclass of UITabBarController then replace `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` with `[self setSelectedindex:1]

Comment: Actually TabControllerViewController is sub class of UITabBarController so [self setSelectedindex:1]  work for me thanks a lot